# Show custom message when ListView is empty and if there is no internet

Tags: android, listview

I know there is a lot of answers about how to show message when ListView is empty, but I want to make two messages.

1. When there is no data - standard "empty message"
2. When there is no internet and I cannot fetch the data - custom "no internet message"

Here is my XML :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/main_progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"></ListView>

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout="@layout/no_data_stub" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see it is only one case, it shows empty message but I need another one.

Comment: Well, I did it only for one custom message when data is empty, I have no idea how to seperate it for two custom messages. Anyway, I have edited the question if it helps.

Comment: Search for how to detect whether the internet is connected on Android.  It's been answered a dozen times.  Then select what string to use based on whether its on or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/main_progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"></ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="halo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

now I can call to `emptyTextView`, so :

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    TextView emptyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.emptyTextView);
    emptyTextView.setText("test");
    listView.setEmptyView(emptyTextView);
```

Now I can set any text I want after, for example checking internet connection.